# Urgent help needed with stolen visa

Tags: passports, germany, russian-citizens, emergencies, lost-documents

I'm having a vacation in Paris with my girlfriend. She is a Russian exchange student but studying/living until September in Germany. 
Unfortunately, her bag including the German visa got stolen. Our flight goes back to Germany on Tuesday and I'd like to know if it is possible to get European emergency travel document with this admitted German national visa.

She doesn't have any kind of proof of identity right know but I have the flight tickets. We also received a note from police station proving that the passport/visa got stolen. Also, should we go to German or Russian embassy in this case?

Comment: Presumably you should contact the Russian embassy for the passport and the German embassy for the visa, which are different things. And of course the police for the stolen bag.

Comment: does she know her Russian passport number? German visa number?

Comment: @GayotFow can they not in this modern day and age of computer databases look that up?

Comment: @phoog the Russians can look it up, but not the police. And it takes time. This question might be better suited for expats as they have competence in students.

Comment: Toni, suggest that you post this question in Expats at this address: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The post was made 4am and thus it's a little messy. The flight goes on Tuesday. We don't have visa numbers or copies. We are now heading to the embassies and we hope they can arrange some kind of emergency travel document.

Comment: German D-class Visa or residence permit for students? If it's the second, maybe you should also call the department that issued it in Germany.

Comment: @AndrejaKo presumably the German consulate can say whether there's any need to make direct contact with someone in Germany, and perhaps even help with doing so. It wouldn't make sense to try to call the office in Germany unless it were impossible to reach the consulate for some reason.

Comment: @phoog In my experience, that might be presuming too much from some German consulates.

Comment: @AndrejaKo fair enough. I don't have any experience with German bureaucracy.

Comment: Hey guys. The situation is still confusing. Russian consulate created her an ID with a picture. That should work as a ticket to Russia but the main consultant said that the ID and the police report could help her to get to the plane. German embassy was not allowed to create a new visa and they didn't help us at all. "Not our deal" they said..Now we are trying to contact german consulate in Russia that created the Visa for a copy. Other option is to cross the border with a bus where they don't probably ask the visa... Painful bureaucracy.

Comment: They might not check Visas on a "domestic" EU flight

Answer (score 61):

1: Contact police, which you have done.

2: Contact the Russian Embassy in Paris about obtaining an emergency travel document and starting the process of replacing the lost passport - +33 1 45 04 05 50

3: Call the airline and ask what they will accept in lieu of the passport for boarding the flight back to Germany.

4: Contact German Immigration and find out the steps to replace your visa and/or entry permission.

5: In the future take a photo of the front page of your passport and any applicable visas and email them to yourself or store them online somewhere to have as back ups in case this happens.

Comment: Also, when two people are traveling together each can pack a photocopy of the other person's documents.

Comment: If I could, I would give You 5 up-votes for #5

Comment: I use Dropbox and WordPress for the passport portrait pages (3 passports), the passport covers (also important), any visas, tickets, baggage,  reservations, confirmations, the whole ball of wax!

Comment: Also important, a picture of my son with what he's wearing before departure.

Comment: It's not exactly the most secure thing to have your passport and basically all your personal details stored on someone else's computer (the cloud)

Comment: @GayotFow: I would absolutely not keep _any_ of that in the cloud (i.e. on other people's computers), but on a USB stick in your pocket, printed in your hotel room safe, stored on your laptop, and stored on a server that _you_ control on the internet as a last resort.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ever checked into a flight or hotel and shown your passport as you did so?  Congratulations, your data is already in someone's cloud.

Comment: @jpatokal: Of course. Doesn't mean I am going to willingly spread it about as much as possible, and leave it along with _all my other data_ on a server that I don't need to leave it on. The hotel doesn't also have my visas, tickets, baggage, reservations, confirmations, "the whole ball of wax" so potential damage is far more limited.

Comment: For "mission critical" documents, off-site backup is best practice.  Having your passport on you and a copy on your laptop only protects from a very specific set of problems.  It's better than nothing, but having a copy stored remotely is much more reliable.  Whether "remotely" means on dropbox, or on your own server, or aunt Mabel has a copy is up to you, but you definitely should keep a remote copy somewhere.  For my own personal use, I consider an encrypted copy on dropbox to be the right combination of accessible and safe.

Comment: @GrandOpener -- yes, Dropbox, Gmail, somewhere you can get to it at 2am.  Hardcopy is also nice, but don't count on it.

Comment: I assume a picture of your passport is not going to get you through airport security (right?). Is that just for capturing data off the passport (the ID number, expiration, etc.)?

Comment: I have successfully used a photocopy of a passport as valid ID, although never in an airport specifically.

Comment: @ИвоНедев Just ZIP it with a password